# Read multiple JSON files and convert data to single CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I receive about 50 JSON files daily that I need to Convert/Consolidate to a single CSV file. I am new to programming and Python. I have been able to get a single JSON file to convert properly to CSV. I have been struggling for days though trying to create a loop to read the new files in the directory. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated with how to read all the JSON files in a directory that were created within the last 24 hours.

I am attaching my working code which reads a single file by name currently.

```
import json
import csv

def get_leaves(item, key=None):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item.keys():
            leaves.update(get_leaves(item[i], i))
        return leaves
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        leaves = {}
        for i in item:
            leaves.update(get_leaves(i, key))
        return leaves
    else:
        return {key: item}

with open('test2.json') as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)

fieldnames = set()

for entry in json_data:
    fieldnames.update(get_leaves(entry).keys())

with open('output.csv', 'a', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=sorted(fieldnames))
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(get_leaves(entry) for entry in json_data)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what the problem is with multiple files.

Comment: You're opening output.csv in *append* mode. If you run your script against each JSON file in turn, it will basically do what you want. Not that it's ideal, but certainly better than spending days trying to fix it.

Comment: One issue with multiple files is that the `writeheader()` is only needed for the first one. Also, if you want to get all files created in the last 24 hours, you're going to have to first get the current date and time and compare that to the creation date of the CSV files in the directory.

Comment: @martineau Yes, good call. Would need to suppress CSV header on files 2-N.

Comment: @martineau I have not been able to create a for loop to cycle through all the files in the current directory.

I was trying to run something like 

for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

to read all the files but that did not work.

I also am not certain how to remain the header for the CSV on the 2-N files.

Comment: you may want to look at the `pandas` library. You can `read_json` and `to_csv` pretty easily

Comment: juice7340: `glob.glob()` should work. You may need to include the directory path if it's not a subdirectory of the current working directory. i.e. `glob.glob("path_to_directory/*.json")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code if a function called **convert_file_to_csv(path)** that pass a file to a csv format you can create routine like this:

```py
import os

files = os.listdir()
for path in files:
    convert_file_to_csv(path)
```

Now the only think that it's missing is that you add the header in each call to **convert_file_to_csv** in this case you should check if the .csv  file it's new or not. and add the header only if it's new.

You can  save the already ported files in a control file or log file to know the names of the files or the time of their last update.